# Using Plancherel's Theorem for Delta Function

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

Plancherel's Theorem states that for $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ we have

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(k)e^{ikx}dk \Longleftrightarrow F(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int^{\infty}_{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx.$$

If we consider $f(x) := \delta(x)$ (the delta function) then 
using this theorem it follows simply that  $$\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}dk.$$

Clearly then for $x = 0$ and $x \neq 0$ the integral is divergent. Also, apparently $\delta(x)$ is [not square integrable](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47934/dont-understand-the-integral-over-the-square-of-the-dirac-delta-function), hence I'm not sure that we can even use Plancherel's Theorem. But having said that I understand that this result does hold. Is it incorrect to show that this result is true using Plancherel's Theorem?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) is perhaps more commonly known as Plancherel's theorem 2. If a theorem states something about $L^2$ functions, you cannot apply _it_ to something that does not belong to $L^2$. It might be that one can extend the result to hold for wider classes (like distributions). 3. As you mention, the integral does not make sense as it is written. However, in some sense the formula makes sense. What is suggests is that $1$ has the $\delta$ distribution as Fourier transform. This is in fact true (but then there is a different notion of FT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: it is incorrect to use Plancherel to prove this. Plancherel's theorem is stated as: "...the integral of a **function**..." but Dirac's delta is **not a function**, but a tempered distribution.

Note that the relation you are trying to prove can also be written as $\mathcal F[1]=\delta(x)$, where $\mathcal F$ means Fourier Transform. In physics we use this relation all the time, and it's been around for centuries, but the framework in which the relation can be proved was formalised around 1950, by Schwartz.

I really encourage you to read about tempered distributions, for example, in [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch11.pdf) paper I found online. The truth is: $\mathcal F[1]=\delta(x)$ is true, but it doesn't mean what you think: it is a statement on distributions, not on functions. The Fourier Transform is well defined for distributions, but not through Riemann integrals. Long story short: the integral you wrote is divergent for any value of $x$, but can we can make sense of it if we extend the meaning of integration and the meaning of the Fourier Transform.

The take home message is: the Dirac delta is not a function but a distribution and the integral you wrote is right but it is not a Riemann integral. The actual meaning of the expression you wrote is a bit subtle at first, but if you read about Schwartz distributions you'll see that it all makes sense and is very well-defined.

Comment: This is clearly something you know a lot about (based on your name), anyway, this might be a silly question but the $1$ you refer to is this the constant function $F(k) = 1$. Using this theorem I got $F(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)e^{-ikx}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{0} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$. How is this related the $1$ you refer to?

Comment: For more details on the different conventions of the Fourier Transform, check the wikipedia article [Fourier Transform - Different Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions)